# Directionality of dipole radiation and spontaneous emission

Tags: dipole, photon-emission

I have a question on the directionality of the field radiated by an oscillating charge and the directionality of the spontaneous emission of say a two level atom.

When I first started studying physics, the simplest model of the atom I was presented with was that of an electron bound to a nucleus. The electron could be subjected to an oscillating electric field under the influence of which, it would start oscillating and radiate an EM field. In general an oscillating charge would radiate a field which would propagate in every direction except for the direction of the oscillation.

I know this model of the atom is wrong, but I also know that it gives very good results in general, up to some numerical factors.

I also know that if I take a two level atom in free space stimulated, for example, by an incoming monochromatic resonant light field, then spontaneous emission can occur, in this case however it is isotropic.

I was wondering if there were any link I could form between these two phenomena, in particular can I reconstruct the directionality of an electric dipole subjected to a resonant EM field from the simple model of the two level atom, spontaneous emission and perhaps other phenomena like stimulated emission, or otherwise?